# Is there a method to abbreviate words down to 4 letters?

Tags: abbreviations

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but this is what I’m trying to do. I want to find words that are understandable in a compressed form (4 letters at the most). For example, Equity can be shortened to EQTY, Galaxy can be shortened to GLXY.

Is there any pattern for this to work that I can look for?

Comment: All you have done with your examples is to remove vowels within the word. Very long words like *Divinelemon* might be difficult, but it's a starting point, surely?

Comment: I'm not sure what this question is asking exactly. You could remove the vowels from every word in the dictionary (except the first letter) and remove all the duplicates and anything too long to find both of your examples but this won't necessarily create understandable English (it's hard to "dvn th mnng of an abjd") and it won't create all accepted abbreviations. The fact is, people use the abbreviations that they see others use. This often creates abbreviations that "outsiders" can't understand — some examples from a field especially fond of 4 letter abbreviations are *a11y, i18n, l10n*.

Comment: Abbreviations can be done any way you like. There is no general standard, but there are many local ones (US state abbreviations, for instance); each one has its own rules. If you're not constrained, use your imagination. Though probably you want to minimize collisions, so look into hashing technology. In any event, 4 letters allows only 26^4 words, about 450,000. That's around half of the possible words in English, certainly larger than anyone's vocabulary.

Comment: You'll have a problem when you have 2 words differing very slightly e..g PROSCRIPTION and PRESCRIPTION. Reducing these to a few consonants will obscure the difference - PSTN? But I have to agree that it's not clear what you are trying to do, or what kind of answer you want.

Comment: Can you say more both about what you're hoping to achieve, any why?

The examples Equity=EQTY and Galaxy=GLXY seem to cut no useful mustard.

How would you hope to treat, for example, 'fraternisation' or 'indistinguishable' or 'agglomeration' or 'conglomerate'? What about 'antidisestablishmentarianism'?